# How to overlay android action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm trying to figure out how get rid of the white bar

[image]

Also, would overlaying the bottom action bar hide the status bar at the top too? That would be great because I would like the images to be seen full screen.

Here's what my current .xml file looks like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/containerView"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">



    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/subContainer"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </WebView>

    </LinearLayout>



   </RelativeLayout>
```

Please tell me what I need to add.

Comment: You probably just need to set fullscreen on the theme in the manifest.

Comment: What do I need to add to make it full screen?

Comment: http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-make-an-activity-fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

Change the theme in your manifest.xml

```
<application
    .......
    .......
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
```